# PyParsing throws Exception in one string while not in another case

Tags: python, pyparsing

2.2.1
**I am a newcomer to PyParsing. I use Python 3.12 on Ubuntu 20.04 and installed PyParsing using pip install**

I have 2 different outcomes (an exception from 1 ) and no exception from from 2 different texts .
I have enabled setName and the diagnostics messages. The question I have is that both texts are similar but have different outcomes.
Any help to fix this will be greatly appreciated

In case of Text 2 no exception is raised
This is the code that I have

```
    prasnaS.setName("prasna")
    parser = englishPreface +invocation +titleLine+pp.ZeroOrMore(EmptyLine)+pp.OneOrMore(prasnaS)+EmptyLine
    result =parser.parse_string(text)
```

Text 1

```
Match prasna at loc 155535(2247,2)
  
   ^
Match prasna failed, ParseException raised: Expected prasna, found end of text  (at char 155535), (line:2247, col:2)
Exception  <traceback object at 0x7f53a00739c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//home/xxxxx/projects/aksr/doc2txt.py", line 158, in <module>
    result =parser.parse_string(text)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//home/xxxxx/projects/aksr/myenv1/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 1197, in parse_string
    raise exc.with_traceback(None)
pyparsing.exceptions.ParseException: , found end of text  (at char 155535), (line:2247, col:2)
```

Text 2:

```
Match prasna at loc 179582(1977,1)
  
  ^
Match prasna failed, ParseException raised: , found end of text  (at char 179585), (line:1980, col:1)
```

Comment: Glad to hear that pyparsing is helping you in your project. But you haven't really posted enough information about the content of your parser, or the text you are trying to parse. Without that, it's really not possible to even guess what might be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the EmptyLine in the end and it worked.
Now the parser looks like

```
    parser = englishPreface +invocation +titleLine+pp.ZeroOrMore(EmptyLine)+pp.OneOrMore(prasnaS)
```

I am still not able to understand why and would appreciate any explanation